# why my ros2 control has no fun“joint_limits_urdf.hpp”

Tags: ros2, ros2-control

i use cli sudo apt install ros-humble-ros2-control* to install the ros2 control,but has no fun "joint_limits_urdf.hpp” in package joint_limit ,why ??????
i check source package in https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control,in branch master , the package joint_limit contains 3 fun include "joint_limits_urdf.hpp”,but in humble branch ,only 2 funs,without "joint_limits_urdf.hpp”,tell me why ??? and use sudo apt install ros-humble-ros2-control* to install which branch code ?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was just not backported to humble yet. We triggered the backport, it might be merged soon. See [this issue](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/issues/1416) and the linked PRs.

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering this because the version of ros2_control that you installed via apt for ROS Humble does not include the joint_limits_urdf.hpp file you're looking for.

This difference arises because the ROS Humble distribution is based on [this stable release branch](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/tree/humble/joint_limits/include/joint_limits), which does not have the file you pointed out. The master branch typically contains the most recent developments, functionalities, and bug fixes. The file joint_limits_urdf.hpp is available in the [master branch](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/tree/master/joint_limits/include/joint_limits) but not the humble branch.

You can try installing ros2_control from the source if you want specific new functionality. **Notice that the master branch may contain changes incompatible with the Humble release. You may encounter API changes or dependency issues requiring additional modifications.**

To install from the source, first uninstall the apt installed package.

```
sudo apt remove ros-humble-ros2-control*
```

Next, clone the ros2_control branch in your ROS 2 workspace's src directory, and resolve dependencies.

```
cd ~/ros2_ws/src   # navigate to (your) workspace

git clone -b master https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control.git

cd ~/ros2_ws 

rosdep update

rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro=humble -y #install dependencies
```

Then, build and source workspace.

```
cd ~/ros2_ws 

colcon build --symlink-install

source ~/ros2_ws/install/setup.bash
```

This would be it. It is advisable to review the ros2_control GitHub issues to check any recent compatibility problems relevant to ROS Humble.

Comment: do you have any idea for Ros humble contain joint_limits_urdf.hpp? 
actually, humble branch has package joint_limits_interface which contains  joint_limits_urdf.hpp, but my linux only has package joint_limits via apt

Comment: You can try installing ros2_control from source. I updated the answer accordingly.